# See all past comand line activity / records

Tags: bash

Is there a way that you can see all past activity / records for the command line, like a 'history' feature in a browser?

Bit of background I'm using OSX terminal to interact with the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your system administrator or yourself have set `$HISTFILE` to something else, your history is stored in

`~/.bash_history`

## Tutorial

**terminal reverse-i-search**

With the Terminal window active, press `Control+R` and the `reverse-i-search` prompt will appear. Now simply start typing the first few characters of a previously used command – and the entire command will display. This is invaluable for those of us with short memories and long commands.

**increase the size of terminal history**

If you like the idea of Terminal reminding you of previous commands, then you may wish to increase the size of your Terminal history file – for even more history storage.

**If you have a .bash_profile**

1. Open .bash_profile in your text editor of choice
2. Add this:

   `HISTFILESIZE=1000000000 HISTSIZE=1000000`
3. Save and exit

**If you do not have a .bash_profile**

1. Start Terminal
2. Navigate to the Home folder by entering:

   `cd ~/`
3. Create .bash_profile by entering:

   `touch .bash_profile`
4. Now, either edit .bash_profile in your favorite text editor or type this in the Terminal window to automatically open the file in the default TextEdit:

   `open -e .bash_profile`
5. Lastly, add this to the .bash_profile file:

   `HISTFILESIZE=1000000000 HISTSIZE=1000000`
6. Save and exit

The credits to this great tutorial belongs to [mactoids](http://mactoids.com/how-to-search-terminal-command-history/).

Comment: If the user already has a "normal" `.profile`, the changes should be made therein.

Comment: @ott-- no, because `~/.bash_profile` is read first and `.profile` will be ignored if `~/.bash_profile` is present. See INVOCATION in `man bash`.

Comment: @terdon I meant the case where no `.bash_profile` exists.

Answer (score 2):

In many shells, you can see your command history simply by typing `history`.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, this shows all the inputted commands, is there a way to get these with a timestamp so you can see when they were done, Is there also a more detailed command which would show the full CL interaction, ie. user inputs and the machines outputs.

Comment: AFAIK `bash` doesn’t retain timestamp-type information.  Some versions of it might, but you would probably need to enable an option that was turned off by default.  As far as capturing user input and program output is concerned, I’m pretty sure that you won’t find that in any Unix shell.  I suggest that you look at programs that talk to (i.e., control) a shell, e.g., `telnet`, `ssh`, `PuTTY`, `terminal`, `xterm`, `cmdtool` (Solaris), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has quite a few options for dealing with your history. First of all, your history is saved in a text file. This is normally `~/.bash_history` but can be changed by setting the `$HISTFILE` variable to something else.

The easiest ways to access your history are

1. The `history` command. With no options, it will simply print the contents of your `$HISTFILE`. However, it has quite a few options to manipulate the history list. You can see all of them with `help history`. The ones I find particularly useful are

   ```
   -a  append history lines from this session to the history file
   -r  read the history file and append the contents to the history list
   ```

   I have this line in my bash initialization file (this is `~/bash_profile` on OSX and `~/.bashrc` for most other *nix flavors):

   ```
   export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a;history -r;'
   ```

   These two commands are run every time I get a new prompt (every time the terminal displays `$`, when it first opens and after every command run). The result is that my history is shared accross all terminal windows since after each command run, that command is written to `$HISTFILE` and the `$HISTFILE` is then read from disk.
2. The <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> buttons. Hitting <kbd>Up</kbd> once will show you the previous command you ran, hitting it again will show the one before that and so on. The <kbd>Down</kbd> button will move you the other way.

   This is enabled by default in most modern systems (such as OSX) but if it is not, you can enable this behavior by adding these lines to a file called `~/.inputrc`:

   ```
    "\e[A": history-search-backward
    "\e[B": history-search-forward
   ```

Bash also offers quite a few options and variables that control history behavior (many of which are mentioned in @Chris's very good answer, I will mention some he does not):

- `histappend`

  ```
  If  set,  the history list is appended to the file named by the 
  value of the HISTFILE variable when the shell exits, rather than
  overwriting the file.
  ```

  Again, this should be set by default. If you notice that history does not persist across terminal sessions, add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  shopt -s histappend
  ```
- The `HISTCONTROL` variable:

  > A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.   If
  >   the  list  of  values  includes ignorespace, lines which begin with a space character are not
  >   saved in the history list.  A value of ignoredups causes lines matching the previous  history
  >   entry to not be saved.  A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A
  >   value of erasedups causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the
  >   history  list  before  that  line  is saved.  Any value not in the above list is ignored.  If
  >   HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read by the  shell  parser
  >   are saved on the history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second and subsequent
  >   lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the  history  regard‐
  >   less of the value of HISTCONTROL.
- The `HISTIGNORE` variable:

  > A colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which command lines should be saved on  the
  >   history  list.  Each pattern is anchored at the beginning of the line and must match the com‐
  >   plete line (no implicit `*' is appended).  Each pattern is tested against the line after  the
  >   checks  specified by HISTCONTROL are applied.  In addition to the normal shell pattern match‐
  >   ing characters,`&' matches the previous history line.  `&' may be escaped using a backslash;
  >   the  backslash  is  removed  before attempting a match.  The second and subsequent lines of a
  >   multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history  regardless  of  the
  >   value of HISTIGNORE.

Putting all this together, I have the following lines in my shell initialization file (`~/.bash_profile` for OSX `~/.bashrc` for most others):

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
export HISTSIZE=10000
export HISTIGNORE="pwd:df:du:ls"

## Make Bash append rather than overwrite the history on disk:
shopt -s histappend

## history -a causes the last command to be written to the
## history file automatically and history -r imports the history
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a;history -r;'
```